# iOS 13 simulator has nothing installed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, beta

I just booted up the iOS 13 simulator on Xcode 11 GM, and there is nothing installed. Usually there are some basic apps (Messages, Photos, Safari etc.) preinstalled.

[image: Entirely blank homescreen]

Also, SpringBoard and MigrationPluginWrapper constantly crash.

**macOS version**: 10.15 build 19A501i

**Xcode build**: 11 GM build 11A419c

**Hardware**: VMware VM (can't afford a Mac yet, and I use a PC since I need some PC-exclusive apps) with 8GB RAM and 4 cores

Comment: iOS 13 simulator comes built into Xcode 11. Xcode 11 isn't released publicly yet. While there are a lot of beta versions of Xcode 11, you should also be able to download the GM (Gold Master) version which ultimately ends up becoming the public version upon release. This could possibly be a beta issue. Make sure you are not using a beta build.

Comment: Please see [this question and answers](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1714/88313) regarding asking questions about Apple's beta software.  You'll need to [edit] your question to include the relevant info regarding version/build and hardware type.   Also, be sure you've opened a Feedback to Apple about this issue.

Comment: @NimeshNeema I'm using 11 GM

Comment: @fsb I added the build and hardware. I'll open a feedback too.

Comment: Thanks.  FYI, I have Xcode 13 and the simulator is working perfect for me.  I'm not accessing it via VM, like you are, and I haven't read any similar issues using a VM with the simulator.